# Javascript not firing from C# Code Behind

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview

I have this gridview:

```
 <Asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gv_main" EnableSelection="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gv_indexChange"
                    OnSorting="gv_Sorting" />
```

The OnSorting method is used only as an identifier for the columns. Apparently C# has no built in functions for selecting a column in a gridview so I've been forced to use the OnSorting method and a switch statement to get the selected column index. The problem is, I need to load all of the data from a column into textboxes so they can be modified. I have the textboxes set up but setting the text of the textboxes from the codebehind after the textboxes are loaded doesn't work for some stupid reason. So now I have to use javascript, which also doesnt work for some even stupider reason. Here is the OnSorting Method and all of the suggestions from the internet I've tried so far:

```
    public void gv_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {

  Response.Write("<script>alert('Wrong messages!')</script>");

        Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'> alert('Test')</script>");

        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Alert", "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('blah');</script>");

        Response.Write("<script language=JavaScript> alert('Hello'); </script>");

        Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert('The following errors have occurred: sldka fhig vqjq  hucxvibg yo7 .');</script>");

         ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "UpdateMsg", "$(document).ready(function(){alert('Overrides successfully Updated.');});", true);

Page.RegisterStartupScript("LoadTxtBox", "<script language='javascript'>LoadTxtBox(\"" + item.Cells[0].Text + "\", " + x + ")</script>");


<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
        function LoadTxtBox(txt, txtBoxNumber) {

            document.getElementById("MainContent_txt_" + txtBoxNumber + "").Text = txt;
        }
```

NONE of the above lines of code work. Each one runs successfully but nothing happens. The last one is the script I need to run, but it does the same thing. Skips over it, throws no errors, and executes no javascript in the function. I've been stuck on this for hours and am physically ill with frustration and anxiety. I'm about to break my laptop, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Also, go easy on your laptop. I'm sure it wants you to figure this out too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this without document ready. You're running on index changed so you shouldn't need that. I'm also not 100% sure that you have jQuery loaded...

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "UpdateMsg", "alert('Overrides successfully Updated.');", true);
```

Comment: Yeah that doesn't work. I'm not running on document ready and JQuery is deifnitely loaded. I guess I should've mentioned that javascript calls run perfectly fine in the c# page_load method.